# Caching relationships eager loaded in the model (protected $with) with Laravel and Eloquent

Tags: php, caching, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

In my `Article` model I eager load the category relationship within the model:

```
protected $with = array('category');
```

When I get my articles in the controller I cache the results of both my articles and the relationships I eager load there:

```
$articles = Article::with([
   'owner' => function ($q) {$q->remember(10);},
   'tags' => function ($q) {$q->remember(10);},
   'thumbnail' => function ($q) {$q->remember(10);}
   ])
   ->remember(10)->get();
```

But; `article.category` does not get cached. I thought it would get cached together with the `Article` model, since it is eager loaded in that model. But this does not happen.

It does however get cached if I eager load (with cache) in the controller by adding this to my `Article::with`:

```
'category' => function ($q) {$q->remember(10);}
```

I know that I can `remember()` the relationship itself:

```
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Category', 'category_id')->remember(10);
}
```

But then it will always be cached, I would like to define whether and for how long it is cached in the controller. As the values may vary with use.

Is that possible? Or must the caching be defined in the model, since the eager loading happens there?

Comment: Just use `with('category' => ...` in your controller.

Comment: I did some testing last night and came to the same conclusion. I noticed that I ended up doing a lot of unnecessary loading of the component relationship. Thanks for your input on this :)

Comment: You're welcome. You might want to extract this to a repository though, so you don't stuff your controller with all that logic. And repositories are trendy nowadays ;)

Comment: I've seen the expression pop up, but I am not familiar with it (outside the git world). Looks like I have some research ahead of me, thanks again :) Oh, and I will add a link to your SOFTonSOFA site when my site is up, great Eloquent resource *thumbs up*

Comment: Search for repository pattern to learn more. In laravel world repository mostly refers to an abstraction over the storage layer (be it db and eloquent or anything else), that will decouple your controllers from the persistence engine you're using. **And what's more important, it allows easier testing of your code**.

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk If you put this in the form of an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `with('category' => ...` in your controller.

You might want to extract this to a repository though, so you don't stuff your controller with all that logic. And repositories are trendy nowadays ;)

Search for repository pattern to learn more.

In laravel world repository mostly refers to an abstraction over the storage layer (be it db and eloquent or anything else), that will decouple your controllers from the persistence engine you're using.

**And what's more important, it allows easier testing of your code.**